# error 400 on google oauth request

Tags: asp.net, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

I have this code.  It returns an error 400 bad request and I cannot find why.

The error at line 31 (which is where it's supposed to get the response...

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.Request.QueryString("code") Is Nothing Then

        Dim Token As String = GetToken("code=" & Server.UrlEncode(Page.Request.QueryString("code")) & "&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=" & Server.UrlEncode("http://localhost:61163/Testing/YoutubeAPI.aspx"))
        'do something with the magical and elusive access_token from this point forward....
    End If
End Sub
Public Shared Function GetToken(code As String) As String
    Dim apiResponse As String

    Dim postData As String = code

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"), HttpWebRequest)

    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()

    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    apiResponse = DirectCast(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription.ToString()

    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)

    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

    Return responseFromServer
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your code but you can always use [YouTube Dotnet client libraries](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#YouTube_Data_API).

Here's a [sample application](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/dotnet/my_uploads.cs) using it.

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim but found the answer.. see below. damn url encoding of iffy google post  :)

Answer (score 0):

well am not sure if the etiquette is correct here in answering my own question but you may find it useful nonetheless.

The answer lay in the URL encoding of content string...

so now slightly amended the awesomeness of OAuth2 is unleashed and I can get pretty much whatever I want from the youtube API :) (although NO thanks to the black hole rabbit-hole of google documentation...

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.Request.QueryString("code") Is Nothing Then
        Dim Token As String = CodeTrade("code=" & Server.UrlEncode(Page.Request.QueryString("code")) & "&redirect_uri=" & Server.UrlEncode("http://localhost:61163/Testing/YoutubeAPI.aspx") & "&client_id=xxx=&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=authorization_code")

        'now i CAN do something with the magical and elusive access_token from this point forward....
    End If
End Sub
Public Shared Function CodeTrade(code As String) As String
    Dim apiResponse As String

    Dim postData As String = code

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"), HttpWebRequest)

    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()

    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    apiResponse = DirectCast(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription.ToString()

    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)

    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

    Return responseFromServer
End Function
```